# Apache Poi slow on generate xlsx file

Tags: performance, apache-poi, xlsx

I switched from *HSSFWorkbook* to *XssFWorkbook* and the performance on create Excel are going down. I search and search and I find that the bad performance, on create `xlsx`, is a known problem. If i try to create a file with about 1000 rows takes 3-4 minutes, is too much.

Is there a solution to improve speed?

Thanks!

Comment: I found thath the problem occues when i set the cells border.Any idea?

Comment: Please post your code, in case there is a performance bottleneck there.

Comment: Did you try profiling your code? Did you try with the latest version of Apache POI?

Answer (score 5):

Are you using "autoSizeColumn"? If so this can cause an extreme bottleneck if you try to do it after each cell insertion. Put it after all the data is in the table, then do something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfRows; i++){
        workbook.getSheetAt(0).autoSizeColumn(i);
    }
```

Comment: Using the Streaming API (in my case SXSSFWorkbook) and this answer helped me