# Read XLSX file Error with libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, apache-poi

I'd like to read an excel file (xlsx) with java. I've downloaded the apache poi library. I tried to import poi-, poi-ooxml-, poi-ooxml-schemas 3.9 and 3.10, combined with dom4j 1.6.1 and xmlbeans 2.3.0.

I always get the error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setSaveAggressiveNamespaces()Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;

I really don't know what to do... please help me. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633247/apache-poi-slow-on-generate-xlsx-file/20680208#20680208

Answer (score 0):

XmlOptions setSaveAggresiveNamespaces() : Deprecated. replaced by setSaveAggressiveNamespaces() in 2.0. You might be using Apache XMLBeans  1.x library. Either use latest release(recommended) or change method call to setSaveAggresiveNamespaces()

Comment: Thanks, but how can I change the method call of a method in the library?

Comment: I've downloaded the latest release of xmlbeans (2.6.0), but the error still turns up....

Comment: try with xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.4.0.jar

Comment: it doesn't work, either... :/
My libraries are: poi-3.9-20121203.jar, poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar, dom4j-1.6.1.jar, xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.4.0.jar.

I also tried to use version 3.10, but it's the same then...

Comment: jakarta poi 3.9, dom4j-1.6.1.jar , jaxen-1.1-beta-6.jar, jaxme-api-0.3.jar , msv-20030807.jar , pull-parser-2.1.10.jar , relaxngDatatype-20030807.jar , xbean.jar , ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar , bcel-5.1.jar , bsf-all-3.0.jar , poi-3.9-20121203.jar , poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar , xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar , poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar ,  I have project which is working just fine with this libs, I am not sure do you need them all, but this combination 100% works, if this works please accept the answer

Comment: no, it doesn't work either. The same error is still turning up. I think this is because Apache changed the name of the methode setSaveAgressiveNamespaches() some time ago, but in the other libraries the call is written with only one "s". That's the problem I think.
But I'm just not able to fix that problem.. I tried nearly everything with different versions of libraries, but the error hasn't gone yet.

Comment: I really don't know I have this with this versions and it works I can just check eclipse project and send you a screenshot to see....just leave email to send it via mail

Comment: yeah this would be great - my email is: simon.bodner@gmx.at